# emulate tail with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a mini-system with only limited number of binaries (`bash`,`cp`,`cat`,`sed`, ...). I don't have `tail` command, and I am wondering if I could emulate tail functionality with `sed`

```
cat foo.txt | tail -n 10
```

I know that I can print lines 1-10 with sed `cat foo.txt | sed -n '1,10p'`, but how would I print the last 10 lines?

Comment: There is many useful sed scripts in one command line that you may need : [sed one-line](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
sed -e :a -e '$q;N;11,$D;ba'
```

Comment: `sed -e :a -e '$q;N;11,$D;ba' foo` to match the question.

Comment: I have no idea how it works, but it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could someone explain this wonderful command ? I am looking to have one command that shows begginning *and* end of a document, and I think this command could help, but I need to add the head part.  

In fact, the command I was looking for is simply :  

`sed -e '1,11p' -e :a -e '$q;N;11,$D;ba'`

But I'd still like to understand the tail part !!!

Comment: How might I alias `sed -e :a -e '$q;N;11,$D;ba'` in `.bashrc`? When I tried `alias tsed="sed -e :a -e \'$q;N;4,$D;ba\'"` it gives me: ```sed: -e expression #2, char 1: unknown command: `''
N: command not found
11,: command not found```

Comment: Can you add bit explanation to options used? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
tac foo |  sed -n '1,10p' | tac
```

but if you don't have tac, you can use only sed this way :

```
sed -n '1!G;h;$p' foo | sed -n '1,10p' | sed -n '1!G;h;$p'
```

Answer (score -1):

Is `expr` available with your system? Then you can try evaluating the desired line number after you have counted the total number of lines in the file.

I created a file named `tmp` containing the numbers from 1 to 20 in each line.

```
nlines=$(cat tmp | sed -n '$=')
cat tmp | sed -n $(expr $nlines - 9),"$nlines"p
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Of course, you can use `wc -l`, if available.

The command to compute the total number of lines in the file is taken from [sed one liners](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/sedoneliner.shtml). However, I haven't checked if it works with empty files too.

P.S. If `expr` is not available, you can use [subtract numbers in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8385669/147021) as shown below:

```
cat tmp | sed -n $((nlines-9)),"$nlines"p
```

Comment: 1. Clearly misses the point of doing it in one pass; 2. UUoC;