# Extract last n lines and prepend chars with sed one-liner

Tags: sed

Considering this file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I can extract the last 3 lines with this *sed* one-liner:

```bsh
$ /bin/sed input.txt -e ':a;$q;N;4,$D;ba'
```

But I would also like to add some characters (`#` ) in front of each line, so that the output will be like so:

```
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

How can I modify the one-liner to do that? I mean, without adding another `sed` invocation (with `| /bin/sed -e 's/^/# /'`).

I would prefer to use `sed` only for the same reasons of [the original question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107387/188792), i.e. I have a system with limited binaries available.

Comment: Why do you not want to use another `sed` invocation? I mean any issue with using `sed` two times?

Comment: Is `tac` available? If so, reverse the file, extract the _first_ n lines and modify them, then reverse the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `sed` to print the last *n* lines use `tail`:

```bsh
$ tail -3 input.txt | sed 's/^/# /'
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

Also you don't need to `cat` the file, see [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Using `sed` only:

```
sed ':a;${s/^/# /;s/\n/&# /g;q;};N;4,$D;ba' input.txt
```

Comment: I would prefer to use _sed_ only, as requested in the question.

Comment: @virtualdj ok, I'll try that, could you explain why `sed` only?

Comment: For the same reasons of the original question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107387/188792), i.e. I have a system with limited binaries available.

Comment: Upvoters! The `sed` solution is from @Quasímodo, they added it instead of posting their own answer. Many thanks to they.

Comment: @virtualdj It would be _highly unusual_ if you did not have `tail` installed. It's a standard utility and using it to solve this issue is the correct way of doing it. The `sed` "one-liner" is unreadable and therefore unmaintainable and not something you'd want to run in a production environment.  The "one-liner" presented here also is non-portable, as it assumes GNU `sed` only.

Comment: @they Indeed, the one-liner is not POSIX compliant, but it is just a matter of inserting newlines instead of semicolons to make it so. It is not true that it assumes GNU Sed only, it worked fine with OpenBSD too. For a one-liner POSIX command, one can use `sed -e :a -e '$s/^/# /;$s/\n/&# /g;N;4,$D;b a' file`.

Comment: @schrodiger, I'm glad it was useful. I now realize the `q` command is not even needed, `sed ':a;${s/^/# /;s/\n/&# /g;};N;4,$D;ba' file` is enough because `N` works like `q` if called from the last line of the file.

Comment: @Quasímodo A `sed` with potentially larger user base, on macOS (and therefore possibly on FreeBSD too, I haven't tested), fails.

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks for your answer! In my case, the `q;` is necessary because I don't get any output (no lines) without it. So the one-liner in the answer is correct.